# How many literatures?

Tags: history, cultural-influence

I believe or assume that Volapük, Esperanto, Ido, Interlingua, Interlingue, and Klingon each have at least a few translations of important literature such as the Bible or *Hamlet*.  What other constructed languages have been used for extended writing, either original or translated, as opposed to sample texts and the like?

To put it another way (which is not quite synonymous but close enough), what is the longest single composition in – for example – Bolak, Solresol, Toki Pona?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I expect it will be longer than you expect. I remember my astonishment at seeing [Alice in Wonderland in Lojban](http://www.lojban.org/texts/translations/alice.html.en)

Comment: I'm not really certain this question can be answered. What do you mean by "extended writing" -- how much is enough? Do we have collections or even indexes of texts by invented language?

Comment: @elemtilas The answer to your second question would be most of an answer to mine!